# Schema.Types.ObjectId default value non null

Tags: node.js, mongoose, default-value, objectid

Is it possible to have a default value in a mongoose schema for a field with `Schema.Types.ObjectId` type?

My problem is simple:

```
status: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'type',
    category: 'languageStatus'
},
```

I would like to use the `type`: `pending`, but it's not a string but `an object` inside the `type`collection. Is there a way to do that by the schema or I need to manage that manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible using the default value. The default value could be a function that returns a value, but a call to `Model.find` is asynchronous, it's not possible to return a value from an async call. The only solution here is to use the mongoose `middleware`, with the `pre` event.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html